problem with Flashing an USB key to install UBUNTU
I made a bootable installation medium (USB key) by flashing
ubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso  using Balena Etcher. Worked a charm, expect that this utterly new version has a lot of problems *)
After consulting various forums, I decided to go back to a version that's more mature, and downloaded ubuntu-22.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent
But:

Balena did not recognise it as a flashable file!
And then:
the original flashed USB-key was unusable (system kept asking to format
it, but format failed).

Question: How can I use the .torrent file on a bootable USB stick to install Ubunto V22 and overwrite V24 ?
***)**Problems:

Could not turn airplane mode off, so no WiFi, while WiFi just worked before I euthanised Windows 10
could not switch off with software procedure, only hardware button
Thunderbird was slow as peanut butter, and would freeze for 5 seconds every half a minute



The torrent file is not an ISO, but a torrent that is used to download the ISO. You load the ubuntu-22.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent file into whatever torrent tool you like & use that to download the ISO; as its the ISO you write to thumb-drive or installable media.

This question is similar to: What is the recommended way to download Ubuntu new releases ISO? Torrent or official mirror?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ubuntu is no longer slow as peanut butter. I think it was downloading and installing software. In the mean time software like LibreOffice is workable.

I still cannot switch off airplane mode in order to access WiFi. What can I do?
